# How to change speech language to one that Cortana can speak?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I just downloaded the new Windows 10 update. I think this allows Cortana to speak Canadian English. However, she wants me to change my "speech language" first. The only option I see under "Speech language" is English (United States) which is perfectly fine by me, but apparently she's forgotten how to speak her native tongue.

[image]

What exactly do I have to do to get past this prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/before-i-can-help-youll-need-to-go-to-settings-and/90e21000-c28c-48ea-a61f-e45d1bc55918) and took some screenshots along the way.

1. Go to your Settings. Click *Time & language*.

   [image]
2. Click "Region & language" on the left. Then click "Add a language" and add English (Canada) if you haven't already.

   [image]

   [image]
3. Click on English (Canada) and then click the "Options" button below it.

   [image]
4. Download the language pack and the speech pack. I don't know which makes Cortana work, but it probably doesn't hurt to have both.

   [image]

   [image]
5. Go to "Speech" and change the Speech language to English (Canada).

   [image]

Cortana can speak English again!

[image]

And she gives weather in Celsius.

[image]

That's actually pretty funny!

Comment: This is perfect.